# Go with VSC: Unable to import errors library

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a go file opened in VSC, and I see some basic go libs imported already:

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "time"
```

But when I try to add "errors", VSC doesn't allow it, and just removes it from the imports.

I understand errors too is one of the basic go libs just like fmt etc.

So why doesnt it work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not allow an unused import to remain in your source code.

VSCode by default uses `gofmt` to format Go sources on save, and `goimports` as a substitute if it's available. In addition to all `gofmt` features, a highlight of `goimports` is that it validates and organizes your imports, which is quite helpful for reducing compiler errors.